# Import data from text file to SQLite databse using two separated classes for file reading and database

Tags: java, sqlite, csv, jdbc

I need to create an OOP model project that can import/export data from text files and work with database. As a first step, I want to create a clean database with the specified table and columns, then I need to import data into this database from a prepared text file with comma delimiters. I have code that reads the file and displays the values on the console (for testing only).

For the OOP model, I have two different classes, one only reads files and the second has all the methods to work with the database (read, insert etc). I am stuck with how to split the actions for reading the file in file reader class and import the data using database class with the values that I get from the file reader class.

Can anyone, please, share a working example?

So far what I have that does not work:

My file reading file code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> readFromFile(String filePath) {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] parts = line.split(",");
            int id = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
            lines.add(String.valueOf(id));

            String manufacturer = parts[1];
            lines.add(manufacturer);

            String model = parts[2];
            lines.add(model);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

My database class:

```
public void testImport(String filePath) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)) {
        String INSERT_CARS_QUERY = "INSERT INTO Cars (_id, manufacturer, model) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_CARS_QUERY);
        ArrayList<String> listCars = TextFileManager.readFromFile(filePath);
        for (int i = 0; i < listCars.size(); i++) {

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(listCars.get(i)));
            preparedStatement.setString(2, listCars.get(i));

            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
            System.out.println(listCars.size());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Query " + INSERT_CARS_QUERY);
            System.out.println(listCars);

        }
    }
}
```

My txt file content:

```
1,Hyundai,Accent
2,Ford,Focus
3,Kia,Stinger
```

What I get when I try to debug:

```
INSERT INTO Cars (_id, manufacturer, model) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
 parameters=[1, 1, null]
9
Query INSERT INTO Cars (_id, manufacturer, model) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
[1, Hyundai, Accent, 2, Ford, Focus, 3, Kia, Stinger]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Hyundai"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at utils.DatabaseManager.testImport(DatabaseManager.java:126)
    at Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to add some `Car` class to match your model, populate your list with `Car` objects, then use the attributes of this object for the query.

Comment: This is the problem that I could not solve - I do not have a Car class as per my task (I learn java) I need to have a hierarchy of passenger cars that is why I have a base class Vehicle and multiple children (like Minivan, Sedan etc.) and none of them can be set as 1 common class Cars so I cannot save data as a common object Cars

Comment: You mention OOP in your question, but your code doesn't seem to be object oriented at all. Your fundamental problem is that you convert your file of three lines to a single list with 9 values, and then index into that list **with the same index** to obtain both the id and the manufacturer name (not to mention that your insert has three parameters, but you populate only two). So first you insert a row with id and manufacturer **both** equal 1, and then you try to insert a row with id and manufacturer = Hyundai, which fails, because Hyundai is not a valid integer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 
I tried to check the code adding +1 to my index like:
`
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(listCars.get(i)));
                preparedStatement.setString(2, listCars.get(i + 1));
                preparedStatement.setString(3, listCars.get(i + 2));
`
But it still does not work: 
`
INSERT INTO Cars (_id, manufacturer, model) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
 parameters=[1, Hyundai, Accent]
`
For the above I removed all other values from the txt file:
1,Hyundai,Accent

Comment: @optimalbox Your loop must increment by 3 (`i += 3`), not by 1 (`i++`). However the better solution is to create a `Car` class/record like Arnaud already suggested.

Comment: To create a Car class I would need to duplicate all my parameters from existing classes like Vehicle and its children Truck, Minivan etc. Would it be OK for the project task?